# Why does Postgres tell me that cross database references are not available when both tables are on the same database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys

Here's the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE fnord1 location '/tmp/fnord1';
CREATE TABLESPACE fnord2 location '/tmp/fnord2';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS fnord;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fnord.shea;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fnord.wilson;

CREATE TABLE fnord.shea (
    id  text not null,

    CONSTRAINT fnord_shea_id PRIMARY KEY (id) USING INDEX TABLESPACE fnord2
) TABLESPACE fnord1;

CREATE TABLE fnord.wilson (
    thing       text not null,
    shea_id     bigserial not null,

    CONSTRAINT fnord_wilson_id PRIMARY KEY (thing, shea_id) USING INDEX TABLESPACE fnord2,
    CONSTRAINT fnord_wilson_shea_fkey FOREIGN KEY (shea_id) REFERENCES fnord.shea.id
) TABLESPACE fnord1;
```

This fails because of the foreign key statement, with

> ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "fnord.shea.id"

But... these are in the same database, are they not? If not, what's the right way to get them in the same database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `schema.table_name(column_name)`:

```
CONSTRAINT fnord_wilson_shea_fkey FOREIGN KEY (shea_id) REFERENCES fnord.shea.id
```

to

```
CONSTRAINT fnord_wilson_shea_fkey FOREIGN KEY (shea_id) REFERENCES fnord.shea(id)
```

Comment: ahhh, that's where I went wrong. I had some example but I didn't realize that was a column, rather than some other kind of syntax.